# Returning dates in pyodbc using the cursor.execute select command

Tags: python, oracle, datetime, pyodbc

I'm trying to use pyodbc to return dates that match certain criteria from an Oracle database. For example, I want to get all the dates between January 1, 2010 and January 1, 2011.
To do this I'm doing this:

x = cursor.execute("""select
    Column from Table where OutputDate > '2010/01/01' and OutputDate < '2011/01/01'"""

Something similar worked when I was using an Access database, but now it gives me this error:

pyodbc.DataError: ('22007', '[22007] [Microsoft][ODBC driver for Oracle][Oracle]ORA-01861: literal does not match format string (1861) (SQLExecDirectW)')

I'm on Windows 7 and the driver I'm using is Microsoft ODBC for Oracle (which I guess is obvious from the error)

Does "literal does not match format string" mean that I can't use < and > with dates on this database? Could anyone help me?

Thanks a lot,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Literal does not match format string* means that you're trying to compare a date and a string. Change your query to the following and it should work.

```
select column
  from table 
 where outputdate between to_date('2010/01/01','yyyy/mm/dd') 
       and to_date('2011/01/01','yyyy/mm/dd')
```

Unless of course `outputdate` is not a date in which case it's best to transfer this into a date as well for your comparisions to work.

Note the [`between`](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/between.php) operator, which you can use in this situation.

There's a list of Oracle datatypes [here](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-datatypes.html); the site is good for everything.

I should add that I much prefer [`cx_Oracle`](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/) for communicating with Oracle from python; though that is just personal preference.

Comment: Perfect! I replaced it with x = cursor.execute("""select Column from Table where OutputDate between to_date('%s/12/31','yyyy/mm/dd') and to_date('%s/01/01','yyyy/mm/dd')""" % (yr1, yr2)